# Allowing different versions in requirements.txt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pypi, requirements.txt

I'm working on a Python project where we have a `requirements.txt` file in which the exact version for packages is specified

We are considering whether to use [this syntax](http://iscompatible.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to allow varying versions to be installed. Is this recommended? Or is it safer to continue using a specific version of each package? Can we trust that the API for PyPI packages stays the same when switching between minor or patch versions?

Setup:

- Python 3.5
- We use PyInstaller to build packages
- Travis CI used remotely

Comment: I'm afraid this totally depends on those packages. Python's scientific stack (numpy, scipy, pandas, matplotlib, sklearn) is quite mature in this regard (deprecation warnings; then much later removal/change), but others might be different.

Answer (score 2):

If your dependency packages are mature enough to have serious versioning, they probably follow a [semantic versioning](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/#semantic-versioning-preferred) approach.

Using this approach and quoting from the link above, there are 3 version numbers

> ```
> MAJOR version when they make incompatible API changes,
> MINOR version when they add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
> MAINTENANCE version when they make backwards-compatible bug fixes.
> ```

So in this case, you could use the syntax you mention above to lock your package to use the last, non-breakable api version of your package, i.e.:

```
foo>5, <5.7
```

(Because you know that in `5.7` there was a breaking change, or that there's new features in `5.8` that you don't need.